# Popmotion carousel fix for new version

Tags: javascript, animation, slider, popmotion

https://codepen.io/popmotion/pen/Kyewbv

This is not working for some reason.

https://popmotion.io/pure/ as mentioned here it has to be

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const sliderX = value(0, styler(slider).set('x'))

listen(slider, 'mousedown touchstart').start(() => {
  pointer({ x: sliderX.get() })
    .pipe(({ x }) => x, clampMovement)
    .start(sliderX);
});

listen(document, 'mouseup touchend').start(() => {
  decay({
    from: sliderX.get(),
    velocity: sliderX.getVelocity()
  }).pipe(clampMovement)
    .start(sliderX);
});
```

whenever I use it clamp movement is showing as undefined. What should it be actually? Any may to make that working?

Comment: examples in docs didn't work for me https://popmotion.io/learn/input-tracking/

Comment: Indeed. The only example (of the slider) that works is the one on the front page of the website, showcasing the "decay" feature. No errors in the console either.

Comment: @Seblor exactly. The one in the website works not sure how the coding was done for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Decay documentation](https://popmotion.io/api/decay/) you'll see:

> Note: This animation is deprecated in favour of inertia.

The documentation of inertia animation: https://popmotion.io/api/inertia/

A codepen: https://codepen.io/popmotion/pen/BMNvqj

And this is a live example:

```js
const { styler, inertia, listen, pointer, value, calc } = window.popmotion;

const slider = document.querySelector('.carousel');

const divStyler = styler(slider);
const sliderX = value(0, v => divStyler.set('x', v));

listen(slider, 'mousedown touchstart').start(() => {

  pointer({ x: sliderX.get() })
    .pipe(({ x }) => x)
    .start(sliderX);
});

listen(document, 'mouseup touchend').start(() => {
  inertia({
    min: -slider.scrollWidth, //0,
    max: -0, //getBoundariesWidth(),
    from: sliderX.get(),
    velocity: sliderX.getVelocity(),
    power: 0.6,
    bounceStiffness: 400,
    bounceDamping: 20
  })
  .start(sliderX);
});
```

```css
body {
  --pink: #ff1c68;
  --green: #14d790;
  --blue: #198fe3;
  --black: #21282d;
  --purple: #9b65de;
  color: #222;
  background: #49a9f8;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.pen {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}
.created-by {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin: 0 -20px;
}
.logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.pen a {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: #6dc1f9;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.carousel .item {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
.carousel .item:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background: var(--green);
}
.carousel .item:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background: var(--pink);
}
.carousel .item:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background: var(--blue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popmotion/dist/popmotion.global.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="pen">
  <h1>Inertia playground</h1>
  <a href="https://popmotion.io/api/inertia" target="blank">View docs</a>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use the decay animation:

```js
const { styler, decay, listen, pointer, value, transform } = window.popmotion;

const { clamp } = transform;

const slider = document.querySelector('.carousel');
const divStyler = styler(slider);
// const sliderX = value(0, divStyler.set('x'));
const sliderX = value(0, v => divStyler.set('x', v));


listen(slider, 'mousedown touchstart').start(() => {
 
  
  pointer({ x: sliderX.get() })
    .pipe(({ x }) => x)
    .start(sliderX);
});
  
listen(document, 'mouseup touchend').start(() => {
  
  decay({
    from: sliderX.get(),
    velocity: sliderX.getVelocity()
  }).pipe(clamp(-slider.scrollWidth, 0))
    .start(sliderX);
});
```

```css
body {
  --pink: #ff1c68;
  --green: #14d790;
  --blue: #198fe3;
  --black: #21282d;
  --purple: #9b65de;
  color: #222;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pen {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.created-by {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.pen a {
  color: var(--blue);
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.carousel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.carousel .item {
  background: var(--purple);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  flex: 0 0 110px;
}
.carousel .item:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background: var(--green);
}
.carousel .item:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background: var(--pink);
}
.carousel .item:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background: var(--blue);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/popmotion/dist/popmotion.global.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="pen">
  <h1>Decay playground</h1>
  <a href="https://popmotion.io/api/decay" target="blank">View docs</a>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Codepen Decay demo**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaLpwR

Comment: Does that mean the carousel feature won't work anymore? The one in the main website seems to work smoothly? https://popmotion.io/pure/

Comment: Actually, I didn't notice that you have posted the answer. Sorry about that. Thank you. There is a glitch with the carousel in the with inertia..if scrolled to left it goes way back to left..and if scrolled to right it's limited. Any way to fix that.

Comment: I think getBoundariesWidth calculation method has to be different

Comment: I also updated the inertia example, it works as expected

Comment: Thank you! Works as expected. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

This library didn't work, if you need fast solution you can switch to another library. 
For example [swiper](https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/) it has many examples and options.

Easy to [setup](https://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/) and it works in many browsers.

Has good rate on github https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper

Comment: popmotion total size is just 12kb which makes it really cool if works as described in their website